# How can I downgrade my rails version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have an app, in which my tests pass for rails 3.0.6.  I've identified a git commit, where the only change is that I change the  rails version in my Gemfile from 3.0.6 to 3.0.8, and I run bundle update.  After that, my tests fail...   fair enough.  However, when I try to downgrade to 3.0.6, my tests STILL fail.. suggesting that something is not working with the downgrade.  I try the following actions

```
change version in Gemfile from 3.0.8 to 3.0.8
run bundle update
rm Gemfile.lock
rm  -rf vendor/bundle/*
bundle install
```

And after doing that, my tests are still failing.  I'm at a loss here.. am I missing something for the downgrade process?

**EDIT:**

I had a faulty assumption that nothing else changed when I changed the rails version in my Gemfile.  By running

```
bundle update
```

my Gemfile.lock ended up updating some of my gems to their newer github versions, and these new commits broke things.   When I refer to the working commit in my Gemfile, everything works again

```
gem "carrierwave", :git => 'https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave.git', :ref => "0d2e9ee8706074059cb78f2f85232caf17327952"
```

Comment: How do you run the tests? Try doing "bundle exec rake...." instead of just "rake ...."

Comment: yup, i'm using bundle exec rspec spec/models/mymodel.rb

Comment: Do you have your Gemfile.lock checked in to git? If so did any other gems change when you upgraded Rails?

Comment: You right aNoble..  that's what happened..

Comment: I suggest you use `bundle update rails` when doing a rails update, and diff your Gemfile.lock to see what else has changed.

Answer (score 5):

take a look at [RVM (stands for ruby version manager)](https://rvm.io)

and [this article](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/gem-management-with-rvm-and-bundler) tell you all about how to manage your gems (e.g: for each project a seperate set of gem)

Comment: +1 (+1000!) for RVM.  Also @Noli, in the situation you describe, it's often better to delete your Gemfile.lock and do `bundle install` to build it up again from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how RVM helps in this case (and i'm using an   projct .rvmrc file anyway here).    My problem was that a gem changed because I refered to the HEAD on github in my Gemfile, as opposed to a specific commit.

Comment: if you are 100% sure your code is works (so it's really rails' fault just start from "scratch" do a new git clone of the project, change the Gemfile and make sure you a in a clean gemset (form rvm, by creating a clean .rvmrc with content rvm --create use default@PROJECTNAME > /dev/null